# OpenSSL decryption and ciphers like "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA"

Tags: c, ssl, encryption, https, openssl

I'm trying to decrypt data extracted from HTTPS TLS frame programmatically.

Is there a way to instantiate ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA cipher to be used for decryption?
If that is not supported by OpenSSL are there alternatives?

I do have random used in handshake and pre-master secret.
WireShark decodes data properly when these are supplied.

Comment: Either I don't understand your question or you don't understand TLS. You cannot extract a single TLS frame only by knowing the cipher. You need the internal state of the TLS state machine which include the encryption key. These information are only known to client and server and can not be extracted from the packet capture.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for response. Updated with more info

Comment: Now I understand. You basically want to instantiate a previous SSL state from the given data and then use it to decrypt sniffed traffic. I don't think that OpenSSL has an API for this since it is not the use case it was created for.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks. Any alternative on mind?

Comment: I don't know the license of WireShark, but I'm pretty sure it is open source.

Comment: It is open source but due organisation and dependencies ir might be easier to look for alternative